# Binding data from one tab to another in dojo (on tab open?)

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have been using dojo 1.7 and have two tabs. I have a value being set in a field in one tab that needs to go into another field on another tab.
I seem to remember that there is a way to execute a javascript routine when a tab is opened in 1.7+ but for the life of me I can't seen to find the parameter to do this. 
I plan on executing the javascript to read the value via dojo.byId and then just populating the value in the other tab. That is unless someone knows of an easier way to bind a value in one tab to another field in another tab. That would be SWEET!
As usual, thanks for your advice.
Janie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single ad hoc synchronization I suggest using `watch` method of `dojo/Stateful` which is a mixin available with every dijit widget (more precisely every class that subclasses `dijit/_WidgetBase`). It allows monitoring values for changes as opposed to hooking event on a function call.

```
var spinner1 = registry.byId("spinner1")
, spinner2 = registry.byId("spinner2")
;

spinner1.watch("value", function(prop, oldValue, newValue) {
    spinner2.set("value", newValue);
});
```

See it in action at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/YyNCk/

For more complex cases see my answer to [Synchronize interdependent Dojo widgets/values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709426/synchronize-interdependent-dojo-widgets-values/10718753#10718753) and have a look at a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/HCx3w/

**EDIT:** The answer to your original question is `dojo/aspect` on tab's `ContentPane` method `_onShow`:

```
aspect.after(registry.byId("tab2"), "_onShow", function() {
    console.log("#tab2 is now visible");
});
```

I added this to aforementioned [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/YyNCk/).

Comment: excellent use of `Stateful`. Before those days, one would attach listener to spinner.onChange and with the argument you get 'inthere' call linkedspinner.set(value)

Comment: WOW! Never have I had such a wonderful and complete answer. @phusick, you are awesome! JW

Answer (score 0):

Simply for completeness, you could make easy use of phusick's answer like this:

```
require(
   ["dojo/_base/declare", "dijit/form/NumberSpinner"], 
   function (declare, Spinner ) 
   {
        declare("my.spinner", [dijit.form.NumberSpinner], {
            linkedInputs: [],
            startup: function() {
                var self = this;
                if(this.linkedInputs) {
                     self.watch("value", dojo.hitch(self, self.setOther));
                }

                return this.inherited(arguments);
            },
            setOther: function() {
                var links = this.linkedInputs, newVal= self.get("value")
                dojo.ready(function() {
                  dojo.forEach(links, function(input) {
                      /*assert if string*/ dijit.byId(input).set("value", newVal);
                  });
                });
            }
        });
});
```

Note, if you need a 'linkedInput' to be bi-directional - you need to create a mutex lock in the watch function. Otherwise one input sets the other. Watch on other sets the one, while watching value in the one input sets the other again and so forth.

Comment: IMO this is not optimal. As from the practical point of view you have to subclass/extend/mixin every dijit class you are about to synchronize and from the architectural point of view there is no reason why a particalar widget shoud have any knowledge of the fact it is being synchronized. I think this is the work for some kind of [synchronizer](http://goo.gl/ENjzx). You will find also a mutex lock in that of mine.

Comment: true - if one would want a controller-view pattern. but why does the textbox then mixin validation if you want it to have that capeability? for sake of argument - the above could easily be made a mixin for _any valuewidget.

Comment: You just reversed the observer pattern here in `my.spinner`. Imagine you have `tab1` with `form1/spinner1` and `tab2` with `form2/spinner2`. You want `spinner1` to be synced to `spinner2`, so you put `spinner2` reference to `spinner1.linkedInputs`. But how will you do it? `form2` does not exist yet, because you will load/instantize it just when it gets visible. Well you can add `spinner2` into `spinner1.linkedInputs` when `spinner2` gets instantized, [...]

Comment: [...] but for doing so, you need a reference to `spinner1`, but maybe it does not exist yet. So you will end up with a condition in `spinner1` to add `spinner2` if it exists and a conditions in `spinner2` to add itself to `spinner1` if it exists. Now add `form3/spinner3` and sync it. And `form4/spinner4`. How many conditions at how many places you have? And now remove `form1/spinner1` just by commenting out a single line...

Comment: If you have two independent modules (in this case forms or tabs) and _module1_ needs a reference to _module2_ and _module2_ needs a reference to _module1_, you know you are doing something wrong. I am a huge fan of the NetBeans Platform, where you must explicitly specify dependencies among modules. I cannot force the same in JS, but at least I can try to design my applications according to these principles. Please see [Top 10 NetBeans APIs](http://goo.gl/ntUYC) - Part 1: Module System API, if interested.

Comment: i dont see how the fuzz is about designpattern. but im pro setting up a controller to handle it as opposed to whatever youre trying to say. the answer was simply to give a greater picture and refine your answer. an the dojo.ready is there so that one widget declared before another will still give parser a legit chance. What Happens In Ajax and JIT Cannot be a responsibility of the syncing monitor